Can I communicate with the PWA thread on the "push" event in my Service Worker?
I'm making a PWA with Web Push Notifications. Right now, pretty much everything is working fine. I add my app to the home screen, allow notifications, and get them whenever my server wants. I'm using an API to refresh data from the server, which is also the data which it notifies me of. Is there a way from the "push" event in my Service Worker to check if the PWA is open, and if it is, then automatically call the function to refresh the data in the main thread? So for example:

Somebody does something somewhere else
Server gets it, sends the PWA a "push" event
If the app is closed, it just sends a notification (what it's already doing)
If I'm on the app, it should also call a function in the main thread

What I've mainly tried is this:
self.addEventListener("push", evt => {
  const data = evt.data.json();

  self.registration.showNotification(
    /* showing notification */
  );

  evt.waitUntil(
    self.clients
      .matchAll({ includeUncontrolled: true, type: "window" })
      .then(clientList => {
        /* loop through clientList to do magic which refreshes the UI */
      }),
  );
});

What's happening is that clientList is always empty, even when my app is opened. What would be great if it were something like this:
/* ... */
.matchAll({ type: "window" })
.then(clientList => {
  clientList.forEach(cli => {
    cli.postMessage({type: "refreshItems", data: ""})
})

My PWA is at /myApp/admin, the Service Worker is at /myApp/admin-notif-sw.js, so the registration scope should be /myApp/. navigator.serviceWorker.controller is the correct Service Worker as well.
These are the links that I've tried:

serviceworkers focus tab: clients is empty on notificationclick - I tried the answers and they didn't work. In any case, my question does not have much to do with the notificationclick event.
service worker clients match all always returns empty list (solution 2) - The first item is just wrong. For the second item, the PWA is opened so idk why it wouldn't be in the "active" or "visible" state. For the third item, I couldn't find anything about permissions plus Service Workers.

Also, matchAll does seem to work in the message event, so maybe it's just something to do with the push event being weird.
